# Is there anything missing to use Chart.js on a Svelte app?

Tags: javascript, charts, svelte, sveltekit

I am new to Svelte and having trouble displaying a graph using Chart.js on a SvelteKit page.

First, I tried to put a canvas and confirmed that it worked, as the code below shows a black canvas on a page if you comment out the onMount function. However, it doesn't show anything after adding the onMount part. There is no error indication in the browser and terminal console, so I am stuck with it.

I use the latest version of Sveltekit and Chart.js. Is there anything missing?

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

    let data = [20, 100, 50, 12, 20, 130, 45];
    let labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    let ctx;
    let canvas;

    onMount(() => {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Unit Sales',
                        data: data
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<canvas bind:this={canvas} width={32} height={32} />

<style>
    canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #666;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That exact code works for me without issue.

Comment: @H.B. Really? That sounds weird to me because the page shows just a white background in my browser (Chrome)

Comment: Have you inspected the `canvas` element, how big is it? Not sure how Chart.js's sizing works, maybe the element is just not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container is probably the problem. [The docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html) state:

> Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from the `canvas` element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes.

You can for example wrap the canvas in a `div` and size that explicitly:

```css
div { width: 50vw; height: 50vh; }
```

(The rules for `width`/`height` of the `canvas` itself do nothing and will be automatically overridden by Chart.js.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Reading the docs, I found that this caused the problem, and now I can see a graph on the canvas!

Answer (score 1):

[Your code, copied directly into a Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/799bacd8016e4b039578f57be7365fcf?version=3.55.0) without modification seems to work fine:

[image]

So the issue is probably somewhere else.

- Are there any errors in the browser dev console?
- Errors in the terminal? (Where you started SvelteKit.)

My guess is there is a JS error, probably related to importing Chart.js.

- Your page would render a blank canvas even if there were JS errors.
- Did you actually install the Chart.js modules? (`npm install ...`)

Here is a similar problem I solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035686/117030